# How to create Mask matrix variable for OpenCV minMaxLoc function in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, alpha, alpha-transparency

I am using OpenCV in Python.

I am trying to create a `Mask` Matrix variable to be used in this function: [cv.minMaxLoc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.minMaxLoc). The Matrix variable should have the same size like my template image, with type = `CV_8UC1`.

My template image has a alpha channel which consists of only `0%` or `100%` transparency pixels. How can I extract the alpha channel data from my image and put it into the `Mask` Matrix with `0 = 100% transparency` and `1 = 0% transparency`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv
from PIL import Image

# open the image
img = Image.open('./pic.png', 'r')

r,g,b, alpha_channel = img.split()

mask = np.array(alpha_channel)

# all elements in alpha_channel that have value 0 
# are set to 1 in the mask matrix
mask[alpha_channel==0] = 1

# all elements in alpha_channel that have value 100
# are set to 0 in the mask matrix
mask[alpha_channel==100] = 0
```

credit to other posts:
[How to get alpha value of a PNG image with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962795/how-to-get-alpha-value-of-a-png-image-with-pil)
[Converting numpy array having image data to CvMat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959141/converting-numpy-array-having-image-data-to-cvmat)

To convert numpy array to cvmat do:

```
cv_arr = cv.fromarray(mask)
```

Check the dtype of mask. It should be dtype('uint8')
When I convert it my cv_arr is 
cvmat(type=42424000 8UC1 rows=1245 cols=2400 step=2400 )

I am not an expert in opencv, but it seems to me that 8UC1 is automatically selected based on the fact that dtype is uint8 (I am guessing here because I couldn't find the documentation about that).